# How to override Material-UI MenuItem selected background color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Currently I am struggling with setting the background color of a `MenuItem` component which is selected to a different color. (without having to using !important to force it)

**The component code:**

```
<MenuItem
 classes={{
  root: this.props.classes.root,
  selected: this.props.classes.selected
 }}
 value={10}>
  Alfabetical
</MenuItem>
```

**This is the css:**

```
const homePageStyle = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "turquoise !important",
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: 600
  }
});
```

What do I want to achieve?

I would like to set the `backgroundColor` of the `MenuItem` without having to set the !important flag. I've done that with plenty of components but this seems not work around at the moment.

> I am using version   "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0-rc.0",

Comment: What version of material-ui are you using ?

Comment: @ArnaudChrist I am using the  "@material-ui/core": "^1.0.0-rc.0",

Comment: The right answer is the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439266/how-to-override-selected-menuitem-style/49439580#49439580

Answer (score 16):

In **MUI v5**, this is how you do it:

```
<Select
  MenuProps={{
    sx: {
      "&& .Mui-selected": {
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      }
    }
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Man you are such a live saver! Thank you! Was searching for this. :)

Comment: In some cases, MUI MenuItem looks like selected but there is just a focus. Can be overriden by &.Mui-focusVisible.

Answer (score 12):

I just made a [working example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/923o96x3wy)

For your selected class to be taken into account, you have to set the `selected` property of your `MenuItem` component to true

```
<MenuItem
  onClick={this.handleClose}
  selected
  classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
>
```

Comment: This worked already before you made this example. But the thing is the !important flag. I don't like to use it, so is there an alternative for no using it?

Comment: And would you like to update your demo to also cover the select underline color change? https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selects/#selects

Comment: Sorry, I went to fast into typing code and forgot about your "!important" problem. It seems to be a bug, maybe you can open an issue about it on GitHub. A workaround could be to apply the appropriate background color in the root css according to the selected state and to not use the selected css.

Comment: Thanks! May you update your answer to apply to TextFields for material-ui. How would I be able to edit the underline of the TextField component which is animated from color with a transition css animation?

Comment: I pretty confident you can change this color by overriding the primary color property in the material-ui theme you provide to your application.

Comment: How would I do it with the className or classes props? :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm doing it this way to change the MenuItem background of selected. (selected prop provided by material UI).

```
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiMenuItem: { // For ListItem, change this to MuiListItem
      root: {
        "&$selected": {       // this is to refer to the prop provided by M-UI
          backgroundColor: "black", // updated backgroundColor
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

These are the defaults that can be overridden https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme

Reference: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override

Note: I'm using Material-UI version 4.9.11

Answer (score 6):

You can updated your styles to this:

```
const homePageStyle = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  selected: {
    '&.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: "turquoise",
        color: "white",
        fontWeight: 600
    }
  }
});
```

This is because of how material-ui styles this component: `.MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected`
The specificity of those two classes is taking priority over the provided override.

Answer (score 2):

To customize component style in **Mui v5**, you can try this:

```
MuiListItemButton: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: '#e44444',
      }
    }
  },
},
```

You'll want to use **MuiListItemButton** component, because "selected" is deprecated in *MuiListItem*.

Customizing components: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/

Answer (score 0):

In material ui 5 mentioned that we can change the style of the menu item like this

```html
<Menu>
  <MenuItem 
   sx  = {{
      '&.MuiMenuItem-root': {
                justify-content: 'flex-start'
      },
     }}
  >
      Abc
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why did you copy the intro of [your own other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77365921/2227743) that has different code? Do both code snippets achieve the same goal? That's not clear.