# material ui: how to change fontSize in Lists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui

I am creating some forms using react js and material UI.
I would like to make the font size on some of the lists smaller in order to get a more compact presentation, but no matter at which level I added the code `fontSize={10}` it seems to have no effect.

How can I change the fontSize?

Here is some example code, which I got from the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y334rqrpp9) on the [Material UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/).

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});

function FolderList(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <List>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemText primary="Photos" secondary="Jan 9, 2014" />
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem>
          <ListItemText primary="Work" secondary="Jan 7, 2014" />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/#css-api) of ListItemText says you can override the `primary` text styles using `classes` props and `primary` key.

Create a style

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  listItemText:{
    fontSize:'0.7em',//Insert your required size
  }
});
```

Apply the style to `ListItemText`

```js
<ListItemText 
            classes={{primary:classes.listItemText}}
          primary="Inbox" />
```

If you want to override the secondary font size apply styles to secondary key.

Answer (score 28):

For mui v5, use `primaryTypographyProps` prop to pass desired styles

```
<ListItemText 
    primaryTypographyProps={{fontSize: '18px'}} 
    primary="List Text"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying with sx prop inside ListItem, ListItemText without result, and dont see primaryTypographyProps in the API. THANKS

Answer (score 6):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  item: {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    '& span, & svg': {
      fontSize: '3rem'
    }
  }
});

const classes = useStyles();

<MUIListItem>
  <MUIListItemIcon className={classes.item}>some_icon</MUIListItemIcon>
  <MUIListItemText className={classes.item} primary="some text" />
</MUIListItem>
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that that the `LinkItemText` uses `Typography` under the hood which overrides the font size you set. You can remove the typography with the `disableTypography` prop.

```
<ListItemText sx={{ fontSize: "..." }} disableTypography >{text}</ListItemText>
```

Comment: `disableTypography` works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add whatever style you need to the primary text. Just follow the sx valid sintaxis

```
<ListItem><span style={{ fontSize: "0.85rem" }}>{Text}</span></ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In material ui 5 mentioned in the doc [mui-5](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/list-item-text/) we can change the ListText styles mentioned in how to change the in below code

```html
import React from 'react';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import LockIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Lock';
import ChannelActionMenu from './ChannelActionMenu';
import styles from './Forum.module.css';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const CustomList = styled( List )( {
  '& .MuiListItem-root': {
    borderRadius: '5px',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    paddingRight: '10px'
  },
  '& .MuiListItemIcon-root': {
    color: '#CBCBE5',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    minWidth: '34px'
  },
  '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
    fontSize: 20
  },
  '& .MuiListItemText-primary': {
    fontSize: '16px',
    color: '#ffffff',
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
    fontWeight: 700,
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    lineHeight: '24px'
  }
} );
const ListComponent = () =>
{
 const channels = [
{ id: 1, name: 'abc'},
{ id: 2, name: 'xyz'}
]

  return (
    <>
      <CustomList className={ styles.channelList }>
        { channels.map( ( channel ) => (
          <ListItem>
           <ListItemText primary={ channel.name } />
            <ChannelActionMenu
              permissions={ selectedChannel?.permissions }
            />
          </ListItem>
        ) )
        }
      </CustomList >
    </>
  );
};

export default ChannelList;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: resolved the comment please check

Answer (score -1):

it is actually very easy to do using `className`,

```
<ListItemText className="artist" primary={props.song.artist} />
```

css

```
.artist {
    transform: scale(.8) // scale down
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0; // align text left after scaling
}
```

enjoy!