# Changing the backgroundColor of react mateial-ui Select MuiList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to change the react material-ui Select MuiList backgroundColor containing the MenuItems.

This is without overriding the styles for all Select and MuiList's. (Changing only the Select name='first' from the below codesandbox.)

I have set the className and tried some classes for the Select element but am unable to see any changes to the MuiList wrapping the MenuItem's.

```
<Select
  name='tag'
  classes=
    { { 
      'root': 'thinger1',
      'selectMenu': 'thinger2',
      'MuiList': {root:  'thinger3'}
    } }
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  className={[classes.lightGreyBackground].join(' ')}
>
```

[How to override material-ui MenuItem selected background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50371315/how-to-override-material-ui-menuitem-selected-background-color) This changes only the selected. I would like to change the whole thing.

This is for material-ui 3.9.3.

```
      <div>
        <TextField select name="first" value={1} fullWidth>
          <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
      </div>
```

https://y5q03.codesandbox.io/

I am hoping to see the ul MuiList containing the MenuItem's (including the rounded top and bottom padding) backgroundColor #999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it like that, you'll have to pass down props all the way to the Menu.

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  menuBg: {
    backgroundColor: "#999" //or whatever you want it to be
  }
});

const YourComponent = props => (
  <TextField select name="first" value={1} fullWidth
    SelectProps={{ 
      MenuProps: {
        classes: { paper: props.classes.menuBg }
      }
    }} 
  >
      <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
   </TextField>
);

YourComponent = withStyles(styles)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually did want to use a Select so passed the following to achieve the same thing.
```
<Select MenuProps={{classes: { paper: classes.darkBackground2 }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mui v.5+, I got idea from Anthony Z also can use sx props look link this

```
SelectProps={{ MenuProps: { sx: '& .MuiPaper-root':{  borderRadius: '6px' } } }}
```